# parameter [extensionId] issue

Tags: ringcentral

I am getting following:

```
"errorCode" : "CMN-102", "message" : "Resource for parameter [extensionId] is not found"
```

in password flow.  I tried to find the reason but was not able to. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not giving correct extension id number. You can get all the id numbers for all your extensions with this API

GET [https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/%7E/extension/)~

It will return response with account id number and extension id number. example:

"uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456789/extension/987654321";,

account id number will be 123456789 and extension id number will be 987654321

Check this ref: https://community.ringcentral.com/questions/89517/c-resource-for-parameter-extensionid-is-not-found.html